# Access SubjectAccessReview objects with `get`

Tags: kubernetes

The following says "I can" use `get` SubjectAccessReview, but then it returns a MethodNotAllowed error.  Why?

```
❯ kubectl auth can-i get SubjectAccessReview
Warning: resource 'subjectaccessreviews' is not namespace scoped in group 'authorization.k8s.io'

yes
❯ kubectl get SubjectAccessReview
Error from server (MethodNotAllowed): the server does not allow this method on the requested resource
```

```
❯ kubectl version --short
Flag --short has been deprecated, and will be removed in the future. The --short output will become the default.
Client Version: v1.25.2
Kustomize Version: v4.5.7
Server Version: v1.25.3+k3s1
```

If I cannot `get`, then can-i should NOT return `yes`.  Right?

Comment: kubectl resolves is driven by discovery. the recommendation would be to avoid creating two resources with conflicting names one of which is not listable.

Comment: I just noticed there's 2 similar resources: SubjectAccessReview, SubjectAccessReviews (plural).  @VeeraNagireddy is that what you meant ?

Comment: Right, there are 2 separate resources.   It seems like a bug that `can-i` is checking the wrong resource.

Comment: This one is funny (it says I can access something that doesn't exist, where I mispelled the resource name):  `$ k auth can-i get SubectAccessReviews
Warning: the server doesn't have a resource type 'subectaccessreviews'
yes$

Comment: It seems I get the same error if I try to `kubectl get` both resources.  So it seems `can-i` is wrong for both of them.

Answer (score 1):

`kubectl auth can-i` is not wrong.

The `can-i` command is checking cluster RBAC (does there exist a role and rolebinding that grant you access to that operation). It doesn't know or care about "supported methods". Somewhere there is a role that grants you the `get` verb on those resources...possibly implicitly e.g. via `resources: ['*']`.

For example, I'm accessing a local cluster with `cluster-admin` privileges, which means my access is controlled by this role:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: cluster-admin
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - '*'
  resources:
  - '*'
  verbs:
  - '*'
- nonResourceURLs:
  - '*'
  verbs:
  - '*'
```

The answer to `kubectl auth can-i get <anything>` is going to be `yes`, regardless of whether or not that operation makes sense for a given resource.